# Add new colors along with custom theme colors angular2 material

Tags: angular, angular-material

how to add new colors in Angular 2 material.

Its specified in the ng2-material docs: color: "primary"|"accent"|"warn" are accepted i want to add something like "progressbarcolor" other than the colors defined in my custom theme for angular2 material.

For eg :

```
 <md-progress-bar color="progressbarcolor">    </md-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Custom theme

   - recommended
   - create your own custom theme with custom colors with [this guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md#defining-a-custom-theme)
2. Override the style

   - possible, not recommended but sometimes used for example when placing white loader inside a colored button.

     `<md-progress-bar class="custom-color"></md-progress-bar>`

     `/deep/ md-progress-circle.custom-color path {
        stroke: $progress-circle-custom-color;
      }`

     - the `/deep/` keyword ignores the shadow DOM so be careful using it, it is also deprecated but not yet removed
     - you can place the code in your global style file and therefore not use the deep keyword

Comment: in the guide for custom theme, there is no example for more than 3 colors. any other help you can provide, please?

Answer (score -1):

Angular Material ships with the Material Design Spec's color palettes built in. In the event that you need to define a custom color palette, you can use $mdThemingProvider to define it, thereby making it available to your theme for use in its intention groups. Note that you must specify all hues in the definition map.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {
    '50': 'ffebee',
    '100': 'ffcdd2',
    '200': 'ef9a9a',
    '300': 'e57373',
    '400': 'ef5350',
    '500': 'f44336',
    '600': 'e53935',
    '700': 'd32f2f',
    '800': 'c62828',
    '900': 'b71c1c',
    'A100': 'ff8a80',
    'A200': 'ff5252',
    'A400': 'ff1744',
    'A700': 'd50000',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',    // whether, by default, text (contrast)
                                        // on this palette should be dark or light

    'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
     '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
    'contrastLightColors': undefined    // could also specify this if default was 'dark'
  });

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName')

});
```

Comment: I am looking for the solution in angular 2 material. It seems you are using angular 1

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md very good guide.