# More colors in Angular2 Material theming

Tags: angular, sass, themes

I'm using Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.3 and i want change theme (https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md)

My problem is: in my projects are more colors than only 3, in define theme i can change only primary color, accent color and warn color. What i i have additional colors? How can I change styles with not duplicate css rules.
I know i can add .dark-theme class to parent and style hardcode colors but i think is not good idea. I should have one type of rules.

Should i have more that 3 colors when i want to make material design app? Or maybe i should not change this colors when i switch themes.

If u use solution from: [Add new colors along with custom theme colors angular2 material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060245/add-new-colors-along-with-custom-theme-colors-angular2-material) there will be a lot of new code...

I google it before but there is no specyfic informations.